# How to move data from one column to another, and to a new row in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Participants had to solve calculations; answers and RTs of all attempts were registered, but in a wrong way. In the example, the correct answer is 14 and the participant first answered 13 and 12 before coming to the solution. How can I move the incorrect answers (and RTs) to the column of the correct answers (and RTs)? Each participant solved the same calculations, so I have to make sure the wrong answers are linked to the right participant.  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hW2ES.png)

I mostly found ways to move data to a different column, same row, to replace empty cells, but I cannot find a way to move them to a new row.

---

Example data:

```
df <- data.frame(Subject = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2),
                 Calc_ID = c(35, 35, 2, 61, 35),
                 Calculation = c("5+2+1+6", "5+2+1+6", "5+1+2+7", "3+8-5-1", "5+2+1+6"),
                 CorrectAns = c(14, 14, 15, 5, 4),
                 CorrectRT = c(28361, 28361, 5261, 7535, 9476),
                 IncorrectAns = c(13, 12, NA, NA, NA),
                 IncorrectRT = c(10038, 15689, NA, NA, NA))
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like Jared has many answers, and the number of answers makes me unsure of my solution. But this is how I interpreted the question:

```
bind_rows(
    df |> select(Subject, Calc_ID, Calculation, RT = CorrectRT, Ans = CorrectAns),
    df |> select(Subject, Calc_ID, Calculation, RT = IncorrectRT, Ans = IncorrectAns) |> mutate(Calculation = NA)) |>
  filter(!is.na(Ans))
```

Output:

```
  Subject Calc_ID Calculation    RT Ans
1       1      35     5+2+1+6 28361  14
2       1      35     5+2+1+6 28361  14
3       1       2     5+1+2+7  5261  15
4       2      61     3+8-5-1  7535   5
5       2      35     5+2+1+6  9476   4
6       1      35        <NA> 10038  13
7       1      35        <NA> 15689  12
```

Comment: This looks right according to my interpretation of the question (+1); is this correct @BrittDV?